# Set foreign key to null when removing element from parent’s list

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

If I have a parent entity with a oneToMany relationship.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
List<Child> childElements;
```

and a child entity with a manyToOne relationship

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

As I remove one of the element of the parent's list I would like the set the "parent_id" foreign key value to null. How may I achieve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot set an Foreign_Key to null as it would lead to a constraint violation. But you can let hibernate remove that record by adding ```orphanRemoval = true``` to the parents @OneToMany declaration.

Comment: I’m sorry but a foreign key can be nullable. I don’t want to remove the child entity.